# add some data members in protbuf class Message

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I want use some data member in every proto Message, so i add it into `class Message`. I compiled it.  Does it work well？

`set_xxx`, `get_xxx`, `ParseFromString`, `DebugString`, `SerializeToString` look fine.

Has anyone tried that?

```
diff --git a/src/google/protobuf/message.h b/src/google/protobuf/message.h
index 925c249..576bdcb 100644
--- a/src/google/protobuf/message.h
+++ b/src/google/protobuf/message.h
@@ -368,6 +368,9 @@ class PROTOBUF_EXPORT Message : public MessageLite {


  private:
+  int64 addr;
+  int64 segment;
+  int64 snapshot;
   GOOGLE_DISALLOW_EVIL_CONSTRUCTORS(Message);
 };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you add the new fields in a new message definition. This definition could include all the messages you would like to send/receive using an oneof.

```proto
message envelop
{
  int64 addr = 1;
  int64 segment = 2;
  int64 snapshot = 3;

  oneof data 
  {
    some_msg_a a = 4;
    some_msg_b b = 5;
    // etc.
  };
};
```

If you do not wish to send this data I suggest you do something similar with a class holding the new data and the messages you wish to send.

```cpp
class foo
{
  private:
    int64 addr;
    int64 segment;
    int64 snapshot;

    some_msg_a a;
};
```

I would strongly advice against modifying the code generated by protoc. Every time you regenerate the code your changes would be lost.